# Using a table header name to set column width

Tags: excel, vba

here is the partial code. wondering if there is a way to use the table header name to set its column width.
the last statement is the place to set the width.

---

```
Worksheets("PDX Master List").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, _
        Source:=tableRange, _
        xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes _
        ).Name = tableName

Dim t As Object

Set t = Worksheets("PDX Master List").ListObjects(tableName)

t.range.WrapText = True

t.range.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 15

' could use the table header name to set column width?
t.ListColumns("Description").Width = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of experimentation shows that this works

```
Sub x()

ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Heading 1").Range.ColumnWidth = 30

End Sub
```